# Checkbox select all row with same field? Using kendo-ui

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

```
$(function () {
        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: { data: items, pageSize: 20 },
            sortable: true,      
            pageable: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    title: "Select All",                    
                    template: '<input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" />',
                { field: "Test1", title: "A" },
                { field: "Test2", title: "B" },
                { field: "Test3", title: "C" },
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

For exemple when I select checkbox at Test1 I want to select all line who have same data in field test 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a function on checkbox click:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".chkbx", function() {

    });
```

Check if the class is the same.
Then you can do your logic inside the function

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
  console.log(selectedItem); // selected row object;
  // loop elements, compare your values and and select lines/checkboxes


} else {

}
```

How to select a particular row problematically

```
    var row = grid.element.find("... whatever your criteria will be");
    grid.select(row);
```